# button всегда ниже input

Tags: html, css, input, button

Вот что не делал, пробовал уже 1000 способов, но банальный код:

```
<input type='text'><button>Кнопка</button>
```

Button при любых параметрах оказывается ниже input на 2-3 пикселя. Помогает только запирание тегов в таблице. Что можно сделать? При установке margin на один из них, смещаются оба элемента.

Comment: Вы бы код прикрепили!

Comment: код выложите или же проведём голосование за блокировку вашего вопроса

Comment: уже привел код!

Comment: Если интересно, проблема описана здесь, немного под другим углом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619536/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/621397#621397

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле элементы формы в **любом случае** будут располагаться в строку. То, как вы это запишете (см. ниже) не влияет на результат:

```
<input type="text">
<button>Кнопка</button>
```

или

```
<input type="text"><button>Кнопка</button>
```

Если же у вас, по каким-либо причинам элементы идут один под одним, то, скорее всего, где-то в коде ранее было указано отображать элементы формы *блочно*. То есть:

```
form * {
    display: block;
{
```

или вовсе

```
* {
    display: block;
}
```

[paranoya mode="on]
Либо вы используете какой-то паленый браузер (либо расширение в браузере), который неявно заставляет отображаться элементы формы блочно.
[/paranoya]

А теперь сравните:

```html
<p>
  <input type="text">
  <button>Кнопка</button>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text"><button>Кнопка</button>
</p>

<p>
  <button>Кнопка</button>
  <input type="text">
</p>

<p>
  <button>Кнопка</button><input type="text">
</p>
```

Заметьте, что, как бы я не написал, элементы все равно отображаются строчно (меняется только порядок). А еще во втором и четвертом случае исчез пробел между полем и кнопкой, так как мы его **явно** убрали (в первом случае пробел добавил перенос строки, что *еще раз наглядно дает понять, что "Enter" не переносит строку, а лишь вставляет пробел*).

**Вывод:** ничто кроме CSS-стилизации не влияет на отображение элементов. Вы можете как писать в строку, так и разделять код "Enter'ами" (что более предпочтительно). "Enter" в последующем лишь заменяется пробелом. *Поэтому*.

1. Либо у вас где-то определено, что элементы отображаются блочно (что и приводит к переносу на новую строку).
2. Либо вы используете какой-то весьма странный браузер (расширение для него), которое отображает элементы формы блочно (опять же - это настолько маловероятно, насколько вообще может быть).

**Итого**: предоставьте более полный код или дайте ссылку на рабочий (в вашем случае нерабочий) пример, чтобы можно было делать какие-либо более обоснованные выводы.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input style="display: inline-block; height:40px;" type="text">
<button style="height:40px;">Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
 white-space:nowrap;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` и `<button>` при настройках по-умолчанию отображаются чаще всего одинаково. однако, как мне кажется, тут многое зависит от браузера. Лучше сразу подключать [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) - это набор правил, который принудительно приводит элементы на страницы к общему виду, переписывая предустановленные браузерами значения.

Что касается вашего случая, если нужно указать высоту-ширину элементов, не забудьте так же про свойство `box-sizing: border-box;` для этих элементов. Дело в том, что по-умолчанию заданные вами значения width и height указывают размер контента блока, без учёта отступов и толщины `border`.

```css
input, button {
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button type="button">button</button>
```

кроме того, я прописал им одинаковые значения border и padding, потому как по-умолчанию Firefox рисует `<input>`как `border: 1px; padding 2px;` а `<button>` как `border: 3px; padding: 0 6px;`

Comment: Не помогло! кнопка все равно в Вашем варианте имеет отступ вниз

Answer (score 0):

Выход я нашел, оказался не таким простым - одинаковый `line-height` для `input` и `button` =)

Comment: это весьма логично