# Как выстраиваются строковые блоки внутри контейнера строки?

Tags: css, css3, веб-дизайн

Вопрос по CSS. Если задать `font-size` > `line-height`, например, `font-size: 24px` и `line-height: 12px`, то половинный интервал будет отрицательным (`-6px`). Не могу представить поведение строчного элемента, когда у него половинный интервал отрицательный.

```
<p style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px;">
    This is text, <em>some of which is emphasized</em>, plus other text<br>
    which is <strong style="font-size: 24px;">strongly emphasized</strong>
    and which is<br>
    larger than the surrounding text.
</p>
```

В этом примере `font-size` большей части текста составляет `12px`, тогда
как текст одного из строковых незамещаемых элементов имеет размер
`24px`. Однако значение `line-height` всего текста – `12px`, поскольку `line-height` – это наследуемое свойство. Таким образом, `line-height` элемента `strong` – также `12px`.

В данном примере для анонимного текста (который не лежит в строчном элементе) и для курсива высота строки равна высоте шрифта (`font-size` равен `line-height`, который равен `12px`). Для элемента `strong` ситуация другая.

1. **Не понимаю, почему в данном примере контейнер строки по высоте равен 15 пикселей.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как блочные элементы выкладываются в документ понятно – сверху вниз кладутся прямоугольники-блоки один под другим. При этом надо учитывать поля, рамки и отступы + плавающие элементы.

А вот как это происходит с текстом и текстовыми элементами внутри блока, а они ФОРМИРУЮТ ВЫСОТУ блока в большинстве случаев - мне не понятно. **2. Объясните, пожалуйста, подробно, как строки ВЫКЛАДЫВАЮТСЯ в документ**.

В строках есть блоки (не блочные элементы, а просто блоки) - область содержимого (content area), строковый блок (inline box), контейнер строки (line box). Написано в книге Мейера, что "Контейнер строки (line box) - это наименьший блок, охватывающий самую верхнюю и самую нижнюю точки строковых блоков, находящихся в строке. Иначе говоря, верхний край контейнера строки размещается вдоль вер шины самого высокого строкового блока, и низ совпадает с низом строкового блока, расположенного ниже всех." Не понимаю, как получили число 15 пикселей в примере выше. **Не понимаю, как выстраиваются строковые блоки внутри контейнера строки.**

Мейер в своей книге пишет "Для каждой области содержимого определяем, какая ее часть находится выше **базовой линии всей строки** и какая ее часть находится
под базовой линией. Это непростая задача: должно быть известно
положение базовой линии каждого элемента и каждого куска анонимного текста и базовой линии самой строки, затем они все должны быть выстроены в ряд."

**Что значит "базовая линия всей строки"?** Базовая линия, насколько я понимаю, может быть только у анонимного текста или строкового элемента. А строка – это кусок анонимного текста и/или строчного элемента, которая ВЛЕЗЛА по ширине в блочный элемент-контейнер.

Понял то, что каждая строка лежит в контейнере строки, эти контейнеры ложатся один под другим вплотную.

Answer (score 19):

Размер шрифта – вещь метафорическая. Даже если вы задаете, как у меня в примере `line-height:40px; font-size:40px;`, высота шрифта будет больше.

*Почему?* Потому что по традиции высота шрифта рассчитывается от верхней точки прописной буквы типа `Н` до нижней точки буквы `у`. Легко представить, что буква `Ё` будет выше, поэтому шрифты резервируют себе немного больше места.

Разделите в своем сознании строковый элемент и блоковый элемент: у них разные свойства.

Смотрите пример: Высота `div` блокового элемента соответствует `line-height`, однако строковый элемент немного больше, он соответствует *настоящей* высоте шрифта.

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div><span>Some text уЁ</span></div>
```

**Что происходит, когда нужно уложить строки одну над другой?** Используется `line-height`, даже если высоты строк накладываются:

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div><span>Строки накладываются друг на друга, невзирая на высоту</span></div>
```

Высота блока состоит из `line-height х количество строк + padding`. Даже если `line-height` = `0`, высота строковых элементов ни на что не влияет, и строки сливаются в одну:

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div><span>Строки накладываются друг на друга, невзирая на высоту</span></div>
```

**Что такое базовая линия?** Это линия, идущая по нижней границе букв, не имеющих свисающих элементов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Легко увидеть базовую линию, достаточно спозиционировать строчный элемент по этой линии (`vertical-align: baseline`)

```css
div {
  font-size: 40px;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted red;
  width: 70px;
  vertical-align: baseline
}
```

```html
<div>Ёнудл <span></span></div>
```

## UPD

> если в одной строке есть, например, два элемента `span`, у каждого
>   задан свой `vertical-align`, то как они выстраиваются?
>
> что такое базовая линия ВСЕЙ строки

По умолчанию, инлайн-блоки выстраиваются по высоте так, чтобы их baseline совпадали.

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Обычный</span>
  <span style="font-size:30px">Большой</span>
</div>
```

Если мы используем `vertical-align: top` или `bottom`, элементы прибиваются к верхнему или нижнему краю строки. Но мы должны знать, если `line-height` инлайн-блока будет равно `line-height` строки, то это ни на что не повлияет, т.к. верхняя и нижняя границы блоков и так совпадают. Кроме того, если `line-height` инлайн-блока будет больше, то `line-height` строки тоже увеличится:

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

```html
span line-height: 20px:
<div>
  <span style="vertical-align:top; line-height: 20px;">Верх</span>
  <span style="vertical-align:bottom; line-height: 20px;">Низ</span>
</div>
span line-height: 30px (= line-height контейнера):
<div>
  <span style="vertical-align:top; line-height: 30px;">Верх</span>
  <span style="vertical-align:bottom; line-height: 30px;">Низ</span>
</div>
span line-height: 0px:
<div>
  <span style="vertical-align:top; line-height: 0px;">Верх</span>
  <span style="vertical-align:bottom; line-height: 0px;">Низ</span>
</div>
span line-height: 60px:
<div>
  <span style="vertical-align:top; line-height: 60px;">Верх</span>
  <span style="vertical-align:bottom; line-height: 60px;">Низ</span>
</div>
```

Как видите, на примерах опять играет роль `line-height`, а не высота самого текста в блоке. Высота текста фактически нужна только для одного – для отрисовки выделения букв, ну и конечно, если мы укажем `line-height` относительной величиной (например `1.5` или `150%`).

Comment: насчет первого примера. высота дива равна лайн-хайту спана, потому что высота дива равна высоте контейнера данной строки, который равен в данном случае лайн-хайту единственного строчного элемента ( спана)

Comment: Мне кажется, в вашей книжке придуманы лишние термины, мне не удалось найти термин «контейнер строки» в интернете. Я считаю, это выдумка автора, пора достать бритву Оккама, чтобы срезать ненужное.

Comment: поищите так: контейнер строки - это line box, строковый блок - inline box. даже в стандарте про них написано

Comment: @Dimon Хорошо, значит контейнер строки это типа одна строчка. Тогда я не понимаю, что вам еще не понятно

Comment: Мне не понятно следующее: если в одной строке есть, например, два элемента span (), у каждого задан свой vertical-align, то как они выстраиваются? я не понимаю, то, что написано в самом низу моего вопроса - что такое базовая линия ВСЕЙ строки

Comment: @Dimon дополнил ответ